# Amazon SES error: Missing required header 'To'

Tags: php, email, send, amazon-ses

I'm new in Amazon SES and I'm trying to send an email with this code:

```
<?php
    require_once 'aws/sdk.class.php';

    $ses = new AmazonSES();
    $to = array('ToAddress' => 'mario@wowfi.com');
    $content = array('Subject.Data' => 'Tema', 'Body.Text.Data' => 'hello');
    $r = $ses->send_email("mario@wowfi.com", $to , $content);
    print_r($r);
?>
```

In the output it says: Missing required header 'To', what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that your entire code? If it isn't, then without your entire code, no one can properly help you with the problem in question.

Comment: Yes, I only truncated the import statement of the Amazon SDK.

Comment: If you can't supply your full `PHP` code, then check if `$headers .= 'To:` and `mail($mail_to... etc.)` exist.

Comment: Without your full code, I/we can't make any `guesses` to potentially solve your problem.

Comment: @Fred I'm not trying to send an email by hand, I'm using the Amazon Simple Email Service.

Comment: No, I'm not using a form. I updated my post with the full code.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I would suggest you also show the `sdk.class.php` source code, leaving out or changing any info you wish not to show, should `sdk.class.php` not be made available for others to view on the Amazon site. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I already solved it, I had two problems in my code:

1. The index "ToAddress" is incorrect, it has to be in plural "ToAddresses".
2. And the value it has to be an array like this: array('mario@wowfi.com')

Comment: Amazingly, I also had the exact same error "ToAddress" instead of "ToAddresses". Therefore everyone should check that your array keys are correct.